# Navigating to webpage from Servlet

Tags: servlets

I am new to Servlets, and am trying to figure out how to accomplish something. Basically I have an HTML page that contains a form that I submit to a Servlet via a POST. Inside of the doPost() method, I have figured out how to get the data from the form. My question is how do I navigate the user back to the same page, and fill in data on the page? I want to have the doPost() retrieve the data from the form, use some supporting classes to figure out what the response should be, and render the same page with some data filled in. Do I have to use a PrintWriter to write out the same page?

Comment: You need to read Head First book on JSP & Servlets as your question is very broad (http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfsvlt/)

Comment: This is already shown in the Hello World example in our servlets wiki page. You can get there by hovering the `[servlets]` tag below your question until a black box shows up and then clicking therein the *info* link.

Answer (score 0):

[Learn about JSPs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html). They're the standard way to generate HTML markup containing dynamic portions.

Once you have a JSP able to generate markup from some beans stored in the request attributes, you'll simply have, from your servlet, to store the data used by the JSP in the request attributes, and to forward the request and response to the JSP, using

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/thePathOfTheJSP.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve your data in servlet and put it in requets object with `request.setAttribute("objName",obj)` then forward to any jsp page with following command:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher('jsp page url');  
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

now in the jsp page you can use the data that set in request with java code or using jstl